# How can I retrain a model on new data without losing the earlier model

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, pre-trained-model

For my current business requirement I need a classifying model which is to be trained on data which comes on a daily basis, and the most important thing is that the data is not available to me after that day, so I need to train my model on that day itself and also continuing to train it on daily basis without losing the training done on the previous day(for increasing it's training data). How should I get on with this challenge. I have read about a concept called online machine learning or incremental learning but I have no clues how to implement it. Please give your suggestion on this issue. Whta can be the possible solutions to it.

Comment: Would you encounter new classes on the fly (between days)?

Comment: No new classes will be encountered. It is a kind document classification problem where we receive hundreds of documents everyday which are to be classified into some definite classes, name and number of classes are constant

Comment: In that case, it is a fine-tuning setting rather than an incremental learning setting. You might have to handle class-imbalance, I believe some classes would be over represented in your stream.

Comment: Yes definitely there will be class imbalance in data, and we will handle it after seeing how the model  performs on normal training. But first question is that how we are gong to train on batched data incrementally. If we get solution for learning then after that we can think of some ensemble methods to increase accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your earlier kernel back to the training, fit with new data.
See keras as example,

```
model = load_model(old_kernel)
model.fit(new_x_train, new_y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=2000,shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jiajie, but I am really afraid that using this method would erase the previous trained model data and start over from new point. I just wanted to know are you really sure that training would start from the point such that it retains the existing training.

Comment: I would suggest when you have done with the new training, then you use the previous dataset to validate it. Check the validation accuracy. I think if in the new data has similar patterns from the old data, then it should retain the existing training. It could be some new patterns not existed in the old data, system will learn new patterns. But if it has same patterns from previous data, the label is different. Then model may start to be changed. It depends on your data. System should be able to learn the information from data, if the data is not consistent, then system will be confused.

Comment: Hey @Jiajie Yu , I still could not figure out how to implement what you suggested. I am looking for a method where I could save weights of a model and use them to train a model for another batch using the same weights.

Comment: Could you post what exact problem you have. I assumed you have a model trained, and you want to retrain them with new batch of data. The `old_kernel` from my answer is your earlier trained model. So we will have to load it back by load_model function copy it to `model`. Then fit new data by `fit` function. Lastly, you just need to save the new model by the same way you same the old one. For instance `model_json = model.to_json()
with open("new.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
model.save("new.h5")`  If you got some error, please post the error message. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Jiajie, I tried some stuff to get things working. I used keras for building a text classification model, saved that model. Loaded that model in another script predicted on new testing data, got some results. Again I retrained the model on this test data. Now the predictions made on the initial data, on which I trained earlier doesn't give me 100% accuracy. This simply means that the model has lost it's previous leanings. I can share the code if necessary.

Comment: Glad to hear you got the thing going. I think the problem you have actually not as simple as just revise the code, then the model works perfectly. It's more or less about your whole project. You may need to look into your two sets data. Is there any new data impact the earlier training? Or you can try mix the 2 sets of data, train a new kernel, compare with the kernel you trained by 2 times with each set of data. See what's the difference. It also matters about the label balance in your two sets of data. So look into your data, look into the whole framework. I don't think it's just a code bug.

Comment: After we have saved a model after training how we have to retrain the model. Will the training done by model.fit() method retains it's learning done earlier. I still have doubt, I have tried this retraining a lot of times but it's not being successful.

Comment: Is is possible to do retraining by saving weights of the model, and adding the weights at time of retraining

Comment: I am not sure what you meant of adding weights. Did you mean adding more nodes in the neural network? But only initialize the new node, and train new data only change the weights on new node? I don't think so. As when you feed data into the neural network, you can't force it to some certain node. I think it must be some patterns in your new data been labelled differently from old data. That means this is not a good pattern or the pattern is not robust. In this case, when you retain a kernel, you will need to use both new and old data for machine to learn a better pattern.